# IBM_DB Package Installation Python 3.4

Tags: python, dll, db2, pip, easy-install

I am having difficulty installing the ibm_db package for Python 3.4 on a 32 bit windows virtual server. I have tried easy_install, pip, and installing the pacakge manually. When I used pip install I am able to reference the package with import ibm_db, but I am not able to use it without getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:/Python34/Lib/site-packages/ibm_db-2.0.6-py3.4.egg/ibm_db.py", line 10, in <module>
   __bootstrap__()
 File "C:/Python34/Lib/site-packages/ibm_db-2.0.6-py3.4.egg/ibm_db.py", line 9, in __bootstrap__
   imp.load_dynamic(__name__,__file__)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The application has failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect. Please see the application event log or use the command-line sxstrace.exe tool for more detail.
```

When I use easy_install I am unable to reference the library using import ibm_db. I was wondering if there was a simple solution to this.

Answer (score 0):

**How to make ibm_db work on MAC**

Make sure that you has IBM DB2 EXPRESS 2 installed on your machine:
       https://www.ibm.com/analytics/us/en/db2/trials/?S_CMP=ECDDWW01&S_TACT=ACDB201

To install the DB2 EXPRESS 2 extact the files into your computer and:

```
cd ~/Downloads/expc ; sudo ./db2_install
```

Make sure that you has your $HOSTNAME variable properly configured:

```
echo "127.0.0.1 $HOSTNAME" >>/etc/hosts
```

Create another user using mac gui 
(System Preferences -> Users & Groups). Use Standard (Non-Admin) privileges.

Create the instance with these commands:

```
cd /opt/IBM/db2/V10.1/instance ; sudo ./db2icrt -u <newuser> <newuser>
```

Export the following variables

```
$ sudo -s
$ export IBM_DB_LIB=/Users/<newuser>/sqllib/lib64
$ export IBM_DB_DIR=/Users/<newuser>/sqllib
$ export ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64"
```

Intall ibm_db

```
pip3 install ibm_db
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `easy_install ibm_db`, it worked for me on both Linux and Windows.

Answer (score -1):

Similar problem has been addressed here:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ibm_db/-HaQ48BhcfQ

Please check if that helps!